# Hidden composer

Tags: cipher, music

Today I wanted to make a "logo" for a composer. I liked logos with deeper meaning so I had gone ahead and tried this design:

[image]

**What composer was I trying to make a logo for?**

Comment: Just want to see if I'm on the right track.. are the symbols related to rot13(- -  v - -)? Because I found all of them and they were almost identical. But still not sure what to do with that info (if it's on the right track, that is).

Comment: Prim3numbah no, although it is a cipher (subtle hint)

Comment: Ok.. That's a very big coincidence then, because three of them are even adjacent to each other.

Answer (score -1):

I am imagining something here , hence Posting this. It may be right. I may be wrong because I am seeing things which are not there.

> 1 : It looks like a Star.

> 2 : It looks like a Speck in a Square , which may be a banner or flag.

> 3 : It looks like a "Protective" fortress wall.

> 4 : It looks like a Strong Union

> Colours are Red Blue White here , in general

Hence it is :

> The Star-Spangled Banner
>  In line with July the fourth

Hence the Composers are :

> Composer: John Stafford Smith
>  Lyricist: Francis Scott Key